# How to switch user with cli in Fedora Gnome?

Tags: fedora, gnome

I know that `gnome-session-quit` is to log out. What is the command to switch user?

```
uname -r
4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
```

EDIT:

I found the hotkey `C-M-F1` to switch to the user panel.

Comment: `su username` can work

Comment: @Ikaros It is not. The command should be with a prefix `gnome-xxx` like `gnome-session-quit`